# Mysql table. Should I use multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm implementing a price database where multiple sellers sell the same product at different prices. Each product is unique, and is identified by its `model_number`. Right now I have 1 seller in my price table. I am looking for the best way to build a table that can list multiple prices with each price being a field for a row whose primary key is `model_number`

The table looks like this:

```
model_number | seller | price 
abc            Store1   99.99
```

This structure works well when there is only 1 seller, as the primary key is model_number and my query to update the price uses on duplicate key update, which only updates the product if the price changes. Furthermore, the primary key is the model_number, but if I have multiple sellers that have the same model_number but with a different price, I believe when updating the table, the database will get confused as there will be duplicates of model_number.

Should I give each seller a unique key for their product? for instance, should seller_1 have a primary key of seller_1 and keep that value the same so the database knows to update if the price field of seller_1 changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the model_number and the seller primary key. That way you can have several tuples with the same model_number as long as the sellers differ.

```
model_number | seller | price 
abc            Store1   99.99
abc            Store2    9.99
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: I believe so. I won't run into problem when running 'on duplicate key update' right?

Comment: As long as you don't insert a row with a model_nr & seller that is allready in the DB on one row, as that row is unique.

Comment: No. the way I update the table is by creating a temp table using the same structure as the price table then updating the price table from the temp price table. Is that a good way to do it?

Comment: Why not just use (UPDATE table SET price='9' WHERE model_number='abc' and seller='Store1';), if you want to update that specific row?

Comment: Well because the data is coming from an XML file and is updated every day using the approach I typed above.

Comment: You can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax with a multi-row `INSERT` from a temp table.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Three tables:
`Seller`, `Seller_Product`, `Product`

Each row of the linking table `Seller_Product` contains two Foreign Keys to corresponding Seller and Product row. The `price` is an attribute of the linking between a Seller and a Product. So it becomes a field in the linking table.

**Seller**: *ID, Name, ...* 
**Seller_Product**: *Seller_ID, Product_ID, price, availability, ...* 
**Product**: *ID, Name, model_number, manufacturer, ...*

This is a common table design for N:M Relationship.

Answer (score 0):

So far your table structure looks good, all you would need to do is add the seller column as part of the primary key of the table.  What you have here is a Many-to-Many relationship between products and sellers.  That many to many relationship has some additional data, which is the price.

I think what you mean by "give each seller a unique key for their product" is actually what they call a surrogate key.  You could give the table a primary key column so it looks like this

```
id  |  model_number  |   seller  |   price
```

Where id is the primary key of the table, and model_number and seller is are secondary keys and foreign keys, but that is really up to you, either way will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Many to many relationships are what you are dealing with here.

You want three tables for this solution:

Products:
A table with products information, including a unique auto-incrementing id.

Sellers:
A table with sellers information, including a unique auto-incrementing id.

Products_To_Sellers:
A table with product_id, and seller_id ( INDEX these columns individually )

With this approach, you can JOIN the tables to view sellers products, but you ultimately have a SCHEMA that scales infinitely

Comment: But when updating the table, will it be able to relate the new data with its corresponding auto_incremented id?

Comment: Why does one need an auto-incrementing id in Products if (as the OP's requirements) a product is already identified by its `model_number`?

Answer (score 0):

```
   [seller]   [product_seller]  [product]
    -id        seller.id         -id -price
               product.id
```

if you need products to be unique, you'll need another table:

```
[seller]  [product_seller] [product]  [seller_price]
-id        seller.id        -id        product.id
           product.id                  seller.id
                                       -price
```